# Access Windows Registry in C++ with CRegKey

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry

I tried to access the Windows Registry with this Code:

```
CRegKey key;
LPTSTR szBuffer = new TCHAR[50];
ULONG cchBuffer = 257;
key.Open(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"HARDWARE", KEY_READ);
ULONG chars;
CString str;

if (key.QueryStringValue(L"Test", 0, &chars) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    key.QueryStringValue(L"Test", str.GetBuffer(chars), &chars);
    str.ReleaseBuffer();
}
key.Close();
```

It returned an Error of the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library:

> Debug Assertation Failed!
>
> Program: ...
>
> File: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE\altbase.h Line: 6146
>
> Expression: m_hkey != 0
>
> For information Blah blah

After pressing Ignore it crashes.

I'm not sure what compiler is used because I (think I have) configured Qt Creator to use Visual C++ but the output Directory os called ..._._MinGW_Qt_SDK_DEBUG

What to do now?

Comment: This means registry open call has already failed. Please check the return value or thid call and fimd out from msdn in which condition  this error happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Windows machine nearby, but I think that there is no subkey named `HARDWARE` into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`: it is into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

That, added to the fact that you are not checking the `Open` call for errors suggests that what you really want to do is:

```
key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"HARDWARE", KEY_READ);
```

Anyway, it is always a good idea to handle the error, just in case.